# How do I use tuples as key for __setitem__

Tags: python

I'm trying to assign values to my nested list using the **setitems** method. However, since Python only allows one key in **setitems**, I'm having some trouble.

```
class Place:
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class ABC(Place):
    def __init__(self):
        self.nestedlist = [["", "", ""], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.nestedlist[[x][y]] = value
```

My place class defines the index of my value within the nested list & it's mandatory to be used for my task. What I want to do is:

Input:

```
myobject = ABC()
myplace = Place(0,2)
myobject[myplace] = 9
```

Output:

```
nestedlist = [["", "", 9], ["", "", ""], ["", "", ""]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Place:
    x: int
    y: int


class ABC:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.nestedlist: list[list[str|int]] = [
            [""] * 3 for _ in range(3)
        ]

    def __setitem__(self, key: Place, value: int) -> None:
        self.nestedlist[key.x][key.y] = value
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.nestedlist)


myobject = ABC()
myplace = Place(0,2)
myobject[myplace] = 9
print(myobject)
# [['', '', 9], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]
```

Note:

- The critical things you were missing were to access the `x` and `y` attributes of your `key` argument (which is a `Place`), and to do nested lookups on your nested list with them.
- `Place` is not a tuple.  (I made it a `dataclass`, which behaves exactly the same as your original code but is an easier way to write it since you don't need to write each attribute twice the way you do in a manually written `__init__` where each attribute is also a parameter.)
- It doesn't make sense for `ABC` to be a type of (inherit from) `Place`, since an `ABC` actually represents many `Place`s.